# Editing Javascript using Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-developer-toolbar

I am trying to edit javascript on a site using Chrome's Developer Tools. I have read about 30 accounts of how to do this as well as watched a few videos. The fact is, when I go to the sources tab and open the file I want to edit, I can't do anything to it. Is there some step I am missing?

I can create break points, step through, etc... I just can't edit. Was this functionality removed recently?

Comment: I can make calls in the console just fine. I simply can't edit stuff.

Comment: You can override local functions and variables, but there's no way to save changes to a file from the dev tools. You still need an external editor for that.

Comment: Actually, I can edit css files but can't edit script embedded in a php file. >.>

Comment: Hmm interesting. I was under the impression that I could edit javascript "locally" then run the edited JS from the console. I am trying to watch the response from an AJAX request and basically need to add parameters to satisfy it.

Comment: Well, I can do what I want with Opera. Problem sortof solved.

Comment: @cooperia put your js code in a *.js file, then you'll be able to edit and run it realtime in chrome.

Comment: @Mahn I couldn't do that because I needed it to run an AJAX.Request on the domain it was running on. If I ran it locally, domain rules would have gotten in the way.

Comment: On 23.0.1271.1 dev-m I'm able to open a JS file from the sources, click anywhere to place the cursor, type... i see a `*` in the tab indicating unsaved changes.. `Ctrl S` to save and the modified JS executes when the event fires.

Comment: @cooperia I meant something along the lines of `<script src="http://mydomain.com/mycodehere.js"></script>`, no need for it to be local, it just has to not be mixed with html for it to be editable in chrome; the behaviour @sachleen talks about is definitively available if you follow this.

Comment: Hmm. I have tried that about a thousand times. I ended up just using Opera. Chrome let me edit other JS and CSS files. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that the JS was embedded in the main php file? I have solved the problem that I needed this for at this point but am still interested in why I couldn't it.

Comment: I guess since I'm done, there is no harm sharing what I was trying to do... There is a puzzle at http://www.weebly.com/jobs.html embedded in the main php file. Are you able to make changes to that on the fly using developer tools?

Comment: @cooperia The JS is in the PHP file, it doesn't let you edit that. It will let you edit any `.js` or `.css` file. Also, I solved it a few days ago for kicks and did not need to edit the page.

Comment: Heh thanks for the insight, sachleen. I guess it makes sense that you can't edit php files.How did you go about submitting the requested parameters? I just stuck them in the initial request. If you don't want to share, that's fine, I feel like I'm missing something important, though.

Comment: I was trying to do this. There was some sort of bug that didn't let me edit JavaScript files. I kept trying endless times... then I closed and opened Chrome 24.0.1312.57 (Oh What a version number) and voila: I was able to edit the JavaScript file. :P

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494237/chrome-dev-tools-modify-javascript-and-reload -- while not answering the question, that page links to "resource override" which sorts you out nicely!

Answer (score 123, accepted):

I know this question is stale, but I just had a similar problem and found the solution.

If you have the file prettified, Chrome will not allow edits. I turned it off and was able to edit. Willing to bet this is/was your problem.

Comment: yes, that helped, thank you @raddevon, I can edit them now but no effect happens to the page

Comment: For others that search for this topic: I had prettify set to OFF but still couldn't edit. Turning it ON and OFF again helped. (Thanks to IT Crowd for that advice ;) )

Comment: Continued: Nope. Turns out that I have the same issue as @raddevon. Perhaps a bug in chrome. You can edit and save the script, and you can hit break points in it when debugging. But the script that's actually running is still the original non-edited version. Example: I edited the script, commented every single line, yet could still could run the script, hit breakpoints on the lines etc. So the edited version isn't even running, it's just being displayed... Of course I relaunching the script in all kinds of different ways without any effect

Comment: How do you turn off prettify?

Comment: @Luke Click the button with the curly braces at the bottom left of the code pane in the Sources tab.

Comment: As a side note if you prettify, then copy and paste back to the original file it will be a pretified original file that is editable.

Comment: @Eoin Wonderful! That totally did the trick. And with the "Local Overrides" functionality, this works perfectly. Thanks for the hint :-)

Answer (score 61):

You can edit javascript in the developer tools on the "Sources" tab, BUT it will only allow you to edit javascript in its own file. Script embedded in an HTML (or PHP) file will remain read-only.

Comment: I am using chrome on linux and am still not able to edit the javascript even if its a single .js file.

Comment: Mildly interesting note: Toggling Pretty Print on/off (the "{ }" icon) will enable editing embedded js, but the changes will not take affect, so it's still not what we're looking for. (Chrome 29)

Comment: That's what I needed to know.  Thank you.

Answer (score 34):

It has some limitations:

1. has to be a JS file. can't be embeded  tags in a html page.
2. it cannot be prettified.

Comment: If after following the above guideline and the changes in the Sources tab just don't take effect, try right-clicking on the edited file in the tree-view on the left and select "Save". A dialog may appear asking you to save a local file, but you can just cancel. Only at that point Chrome's edit history finally shows that the edit has stuck.

Comment: i was going crazy because this new file had embedded js but I couldn't edit..i didn't understand why..thank you #gcb and #welah

Comment: Is it possible to un include a JS file from the list under the `Sources` tab of the Developer tools?

Comment: @techie_28 not sure, open another question. But i would write a quick extension for that.

Answer (score 16):

I don't know if you need this to save permanently, but if you need to just temporarily modify the js:

I can copy that javascript I want to modify into a text editor, edit it, then paste it in the console and it will redefine any functions or whatever that I need to be redefined.

for instance, if the page has:

```
<script>
var foo = function() { console.log("Hi"); }
</script>
```

I can take the content between the script, edit it, then enter it into the debugger like:

```
foo = function() { console.log("DO SOMETHING DIFFERENT"); }
```

and it will work for me.

Or if you have like,

```
function foo() {
    doAThing();
}
```

You can just enter

```
function foo() {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

and foo will be redefined.

Probably not the best workaround, but it works. Will last until you reload the page.

Answer (score 10):

I did search "chrome dev tool edit javascript". This page is the first search result. But it is too outdated, it does not help me.

I am using Chrome 73, this version of Chrome has "Enable Local Overrides" option. Using the function, I could edit a javascript and could run and debug.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

1. In the devtools preferences check the Enable local overrides.
2. Go to network tab, find the file you want to edit, rigth click on it and select Save for overrides (on the sources/overrides tab you need to add a local folder)
3. The file appears in a new tab on the Sources tab as local copy, so you can edit this file, and after site reload the new (and edited) override file will load on the site!