# Google Chrome source code reloading

Tags: google-chrome, reload

How do I reload a page in Google Chrome, so the source code will not change? 
In other words, if I change some text on the page with developer tools, and reload the page it loads the source code from the server. How can I reload the page so it will keep my previous changes I made?

To be more specific:

1. I enter a page
2. I edit content with Developer Tools
3. I press reload
4. I get the original version

As far as I know I must forbid Google Chrome to download source code from server or load a cached version, but how I to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Dev Tools - Modify javascript and reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494237/chrome-dev-tools-modify-javascript-and-reload)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know isnt this possible, because when you press reload, Chrome automatically "deletes" your webpage that is shown at the moment and gets the source from the server again. You could try to save your changed webpage in the cache of a proxy server and then get it from there.