# Why does the code in Chrome console not execute after window.location.reload?

Tags: javascript, onload

I'm using the Chrome console using the snippet tool.

When I execute my code without the `window.location.reload` I can refresh the page manually and the code runs and selects the button I need it to. Is there any way to make it reload the page when I run the code, and subsequently run the function?

```js
window.location.reload()
window.onload=stephen;

function stephen(){
    selectedValue('mills');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

On topic: unfortunately console allows one to debug a **loaded** page, therefore your snippet won't run. Basically each page load is a new console session. There might be a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494237/chrome-dev-tools-modify-javascript-and-reload)

Comment: Thank you for your reply is there any way i can do this in an external js file or will i have to use some sort of api for the website i am trying this on? many thanks.

Comment: Try using an add-on called greasemonkey or some modern alternative

Comment: Thank you will take a look many thanks